# How do you use the Seq. average by function in F# to average data in one row, grouped by data in another row?

Tags: f#

I have two rows, State and Income. There are multiple rows with the same State, but I want one row with each State. Therefore I want to average all the income data by State, so I can get an average per State and only one value/row per state. This is my attempt to average values in the Income row by the State row. 
I have grouped the Sequence like so:

Seq.groupBy(fun row -> row.State)

But when I try to average the data in the income column which is already grouped by State (from above):

Seq.average(fun row -> row.Income)

It gives me this error:

" error FS0001: Expecting a type supporting the operator '+' but given a function type. You may be missing an argument to a function."

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to pass in a function, you want [`Seq.averageBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.averageby%5B't%2C%5Eu%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D), not [`Seq.average`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.average%5b%5et%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d). `Seq.average` takes a sequence of numbers, whereas `Seq.averageBy` takes a *function* and a sequence of things of type T (and the function should be one that takes something of type T and returns a number).

Also, if you're using `Seq.groupBy` first, be aware that it returns a sequence of tuples, where the first element of the tuple is the key, and the second is a sequence of values that have that key. (In the type signature, this is represented by the type `seq<'Key * seq<'T>>`). So what you want is a little bit complicated, and I'll walk you through it:

1. First, if you wanted to get the average of your whole sequence, then it would be `rows |> Seq.averageBy(fun row -> row.Income)`.
2. But first, you're calling `Seq.groupBy`, which returns a sequence of tuples. If you did `rows |> Seq.groupBy (fun row -> row.State) |> Seq.averageBy (fun row -> row.Income)`, then you'd get an error saying that a tuple doesn't have a property called `Income`. Because the `Seq.groupBy` call has turned your data into something like this:

   ```
   seq {
       (TX, seq { row1, row4, row7 })
       (CA, seq { row2, row5, row8 })
       (NY, seq { row3, row6, row9 })
   }
   ```
3. What you want at the end is:

   ```
   seq {
       (TX, 12345.0)
       (CA, 34567.0)
       (NY, 23456.0)
   }
   ```
4. Therefore, what you want is to take the sequence produced by `Seq.groupBy` and *transform* it in a way that keeps the keys but transforms the sequence of values. Whenever you think "I want to keep this sequence but turn its contents into something else", you want [`Seq.map`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.map%5b't,'u%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d).
5. `Seq.map` takes a function that takes a single item of type T (whatever T might be), but we can use [destructuring in function parameters](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/tuples/) (look for the `addOneToTuple` example on that page) to make it simpler: since we know that the "outer" sequence that we're mapping over is a tuple of `(key, values)`, we can write the function to take a `(key, values)` tuple: `fun (key, values) -> key, (values |> Seq.averageBy ...)` would be what you want.
6. Therefore, the pipeline that you want to use, to group first and then average the values within each group (while keeping the group keys) is going to look like this:

   ```
   rows
   |> Seq.groupBy (fun row -> row.State)
   |> Seq.map (fun (state, groupedRows) ->
       let averageIncome = groupedRows |> Seq.averageBy (fun row -> row.Income)
       (state, averageIncome))
   ```

And that should do it. Note that in the final `Seq.map` step, I had to make sure to return a tuple of `(state, averageIncome)`; if I had just returned the result of `groupedRows |> Seq.averageBy (fun row -> row.Income)`, then I would have been mapping a tuple down to a single value, and you would have gotten a seq of average incomes that no longer had the state attached.

I hope this helps you see the process of how you go about solving a problem like this one in F#. There are [lots of different functions that work on collections like lists or sequences](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/list-module-functions/) and it can be a bit confusing at first. But the basic approach is the same whether you're a beginner or an experienced F# developer: you start by saying "What kind of data do I have, and what kind of data do I want to have when I finish?" And then you look for a function that has the right "shape" to turn data of type A into data of type B; if there's no single function for that, you put together several functions like building blocks to get the overall function that you need. (E.g., how we combined `Seq.map` and `Seq.averageBy` here).

Comment: Thanks much. What if there are other values in the sequence besides State and Income that I want. Do I just specify them in the Let Function?

Comment: That question is vague enough that I'm not quite sure how to answer it. Do you mean that the items in the sequence have other properties besides State and Income? Then yeah, you might change the final function to return something like `(state, averageIncome, averagePopulation)` where averagePopulation would be something made by `Seq.averageBy (fun row -> row.Population)`. If you mean something else, then let me know more specifically what you need and I'll give you a better answer.

Comment: You can't format code in comments; I suggest asking a new question about this error so that you can format your code properly. But at a glance, I see you calling `Seq.groupBy`, which creates a seq of 2-tuples of (state, groupedRows), and then passing that into a `Seq.map` where your function expects a 3-tuple of (state, country, groupedRows). Where would the country come from? You don't have any code in the pipeline up to that point that would pull it out into a separate tuple member. That looks like your first mistake.

Comment: When you're building up a data-transforming pipeline like this one, I find that it's useful to do it one step at a time, and have the last step of your pipeline be `|> (fun result -> printfn "Pipeline produced: %A" result)`. The `%A` format code means "Figure out what type of thing this is, and print it appropriately", so it's very useful for debugging type errors like the one you're getting. Then add each step of your pipeline one at a time, and re-run the code and see what that step is causing your pipeline to produce.

Comment: Note that the code `fun result -> printfn "Pipeline produced: %A" result` can be condensed down to just `printfn "Pipeline produced: %A"`. But since you seem to be a beginner at F#, I recommend writing the long form (with `fun result` at the beginning), because you may not yet understand what's going on with the short form. (What's going on is [currying](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/currying/), a very useful technique once you understand it — but focus on getting your head wrapped around pipelines first, then you can worry about currying later).